# A function is not affecting a variable

Tags: python, function

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
score = 0

def plus_point():
    score += 1
    return score

plus_point()

print(score)
```

The output is still 0.

Comment: This code raises the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment`. Are you sure that this is exactly the version of your code about which you are asking this  question?

Comment: Which means that the `score` variable you defined in the function is not the same `score` variable that you defined outside the function.

Comment: In more formal languages like Java this would not be a problem, as you are required to *explicitly* declare your variables in those languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `global`, change your function to:

```
def plus_point():
    global score
    score += 1
    return score
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Don't mean to bother you, but could you please explain why do you need to use global?

Comment: @scrap_tech_guy I suggest reading [python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) then [python docs for global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) or

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it